# the trait bound `i64: Termination` is not satisfied required for `Result<i64, TestError>` to implement `Termination`

Tags: rust, error-handling

Just learning rust and trying to understand "?" operator.

have following code:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
enum TestError {
    Case1,
    Case2,
    Case3,
}

fn test_question(case: String) -> Result<i64, TestError> {
    if case == "case1" {
        Err(TestError::Case1)
    } else if case == "case2" {
        Err(TestError::Case2)
    } else if case == "case3" {
        Err(TestError::Case3)
    } else {Ok(1)}
}

fn main() -> Result<i64, TestError> {
    println!("Hello, world!");

    let foo = test_question ("pass".to_string())?;
    println!("{}", foo);

    Ok(foo)
}
```

Receiving error in "Title" - what am I doing wrong?

Shawn

Expecting program to compile and return 1.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have this issue even without `Result` if you attempt to return `i64` from `main`:

```
fn main() -> i64 {
    todo!()
}
```

```
error[E0277]: `main` has invalid return type `i64`
 --> src/main.rs:1:14
  |
1 | fn main() -> i64 {
  |              ^^^ `main` can only return types that implement `Termination`
  |
  = help: consider using `()`, or a `Result`
```

You can only return values from `main` if they implement [`Termination`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/trait.Termination.html).  The purpose of this trait is to convert a value to an [`ExitCode`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.ExitCode.html) and there is no one-to-one mapping from `i64` to exit codes, because not all platforms support the full domain of values.  (For example, Linux only supports values 0-255, which is the domain of `u8`.)  Therefore, `i64` doesn't implement `Termination`, which is why the compiler tells you that in the error message.

Consider returning `Result<(), TestError>` instead.

If you want the program to actually terminate with the exact return code 1, change the return type to `Result<ExitCode, TestError>` and return `Ok(ExitCode::from(1))`.

Comment: To terminate with return code 1, you can also return [`ExitCode::from (1)`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/process/struct.ExitCode.html#impl-From%3Cu8%3E-for-ExitCode).

Comment: @Jmb Ah, somehow I missed that was possible. I assumed it was "enum-like" where the constants were the only way to obtain a value.